# Poussière en suspension dans un rayon de soleil

Tags: demande-de-mot

Tous ont probablement pu observer à une époque ou une autre de leur vie de la poussière en suspension dans un rayon de soleil entrant dans une pièce sombre.

À moins d’être aveugle, il me semble que c’est une expérience humaine incontournable, aussi l’absence apparente de terme approprié pour désigner cette poussière dans des langues aussi vastes que le français et l’anglais<sup>1</sup> est-il pour moi une source de surprise sans cesse renouvelée.

En connaît-on un qui pourrait faire l’affaire ? Ou à la rigueur une expression simple en deux mots, possiblement même liés par une conjonction ?

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>*Voir [cette question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/253377/single-word-for-floating-dust-visible-in-sunlight) sur English Language & Usage, qui n’a pas de réponse véritablement satisfaisante*.</sub>

Comment: J'espère que vous voudrez bien excuser ma platitude. Il est vrai que ce phénomène interrogeait déjà Aristote. Maintenant... à mon sens... la raison pour laquelle il n'est pas de mot pour désigner la poussière est que la poussière c'est... de la poussière. (Oui... je sais... ;-) Le phénomène curieux voire merveilleux c'est le *rai* qui n'existerait pas sans poussière.

Comment: @aCOSwt Vous devriez soumettre une réponse. Quand il n'y a pas de réponse directe, les raisons expliquant pourquoi il n'y en a pas, ou les manières de contourner l'inexistence, peuvent sûrement servir de réponse...

Comment: Ha pfff! Vous me demandez une réponse en bonne et due forme sur la fameuse ***MATIÈRE SUBTILE*** ? ... rePfff!! Il faudrait pour cela que je la commence par *Je vous supplie de croire* et que j'utilise ensuite des imparfaits du subjonctif et... j'ai pas envie! ;-) Ha! J'allais oublier! sur le propos un document pas mal fait avec plein de mots dedans... : https://www.persee.fr/doc/rhs_0048-7996_1950_num_3_3_2829

Answer (score 4):

***Pas une réponse, simplement une idée***

J’ai trouvé dans le [Glossaire du parler français au Canada](http://bibnum2.banq.qc.ca/bna/numtxt/179630.pdf) le terme ***manivole***, que je n’avais jamais entendu de toute ma vie, et que je suspecte donc d’être en voie de sortir entièrement de l’usage. Ce mot désignerait, dans la langue canadienne-française :

> 1° Poussière qui vole au vent, quand on secoue un tapis, une étoffe ; cendre très fine.
>   2° Poussière de farine qui s’échappe des meules dans les meuneries et se pose sur les murs, les plafonds, etc. ; menues graines qui restent sur la batteuse.

Si le terme approprié à la question devait se révéler être inexistant, alors puisque celui-ci est en voie de disparition, il pourrait probablement supporter une extension de sens qui ne serait pas si loin de ses sens primordiaux.

Comment: Puisqu'il s'agit de créer une extension de sens  autant créer aussi un mot, comme cela a été fait en anglais, comme peut être « lucivole » sur le modèle de « luciole »  en gardant le v de « manivole » (des « manivoles lumineuses»).

Comment: Il ne s'agit pas d'une proposition, ni d'une suggestion; après tout il doit bien y avoir d'autres possibilités et même, pourquoi pas une plus heureuse; c'est seulement un exemple à fin de montrer qu'il n'y aurait qu'une difficulté négligeable pour aller jusqu'au fond de la question (si on lui reconnait ce fond).

Comment: Ce que je voulais dire, c'est qu'il y a une différence entre proposer un terme chez-moi (où je n'ai que quelques personnes à convaincre de son bien-fondé) et proposer un terme à la Francophonie (où des millions de personnes ne sauront même pas que j’ai proposé quoi que ce soit et n'en dormiront pas plus mal). Des organismes où des centaines de personnes travaillent, comme l’OQLF, proposent des termes qui ne sont ultimement pas acceptés par les usagers de la langue française. D'où mon doute quant à la possibilité que StackExchange puisse jamais devenir une source de mots nouveaux.

Comment: Bien sûr, tout un système est nécessaire pour ce genre d'entreprise et je crois qu'il n'existe rien, en particulier aucune organisation avec un souci de préserver un  français uniforme sur toute la francophonie.

Answer (score 2):

Techniquement, on peut appeler ces particules en suspension, ou l'air chargé de ces particules, un **aérosol**, cf. [TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/a%C3%A9rosol)

> CHIM. Suspension, dans l'air ou dans un gaz, de particules solides ou plus généralement liquides, et très fines. Système réalisant cette suspension.

Je trouve cependant [**manivole**](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/32467/1109) (+1) bien plus poétique...

Le faisceau d'une source lumineuse puissante (soleil ou autre) matérialisé par la présence de ces particules s'appelle un [**rai**](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/rai), déjà évoqué par aCOSwt.

Answer (score 1):

Pour the terme assez spécifique « mote » en anglais je trouve dans un de mes dictionnaires la traduction « atome de poussière », qui tend à laisser penser de par sa nature de périphrase qu'il n'existe probablement pas de terme spécifique  en français.

Comment: @Montéedelait Il ne me semble pas qu'il ait une alternative. On dit « graine de poussière » au Canada, et non pas « grain de poussière » comme en France ?

Answer (score 1):

De par la nature physique du phénomène, peut-être s'est-on simplement attaché à décrire le phénomène plutôt que les agents. On parle généralement de lumière diffuse, ou bien de particule diffusante. J'imagine que le meilleur moyen de caractériser ces particules est de dire qu'elles sont en suspension, et qu'elles diffusent la lumière. Je ne connais cependant pas non plus de terme simple pour les désigner.

Answer (score 0):

Les scientifiques l'appellent « effet Tyndall. »